# why my subclass inherits property that has not been specified in base-class's super() statement?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I'm learning JS OOP, when creating a Product (parent) class:

```
// Parent Class
class Product {
    constructor (name, categorie, htPrice) {
        this.name = name
        this.categorie = categorie
        this.htPrice = htPrice
    }
}
```

And then a derived class:

```
// Derived Class
class Laptop extends Product {
    constructor (company, store, name, htPrice) {
        super(name, htPrice)
        this.company = company
        this.store = store
    }
}
```

I specified the properties I want to be inherited from the base-class, namely (name, htPrice)

```
super(name, htPrice)
```

and add new  properties, namely (company and store).
But when Initiating an instance from the derived class passing it some values and console log it, I was surprised that "categorie" property is inherited too! and took one of the values!

```
let item1 = new Laptop('Dell', 'E-bay', 'dell-Latitue', 700)
console.log(item1)
//Laptop {name: 'dell-Latitue', categorie: 700, htPrice: undefined, company: 'Dell', store: 'E-bay'}
```

Comment: All the props are inherited.  I think you mean you're specifying the ones you want initialized. In the parent class constructor, the second param is categorie, but the subclass is invoking it with htPrice, here `super(name, htPrice)`

Comment: Thank you, "All the props are inherited." is the key for me :)

Answer (score 2):

> I specified the properties I want to be inherited from the base-class

No. You simply called the parent constructor (`super`) with two arguments, despite it having three parameters. The usual JS function call semantics apply: the first parameter (`name`) is assigned the first argument (`name`), the second parameter (`categorie`) is assigned the second argument (`htPrice`), the third parameter (`htPrice`) is assigned the value `undefined`. And the `Product` constructor always creates three properties, there's no `if` statement or anything.

You might want to use `super(name, undefined, htPrice);` instead. However, it's usually a questionable idea to try inheriting only a subset of properties - in OOP, a subclass instance has (must have!) all the properties and methods of its base class, and needs to be able to be used everywhere in place of an instance of the base class. So if a `Laptop` really has no category, then maybe inheritance is the wrong choice to model this. Or maybe all laptops are in the `Laptop` category? Then write `super(name, 'Laptop', htPrice);`.